# Creating list of dictionaries from big csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, generator, avro

I've a very big csv file (10 gb) and I'd like to read it and create a list of dictionaries where each dictionary represent a line in the csv.
Something like

```
[{'value1': '20150302', 'value2': '20150225','value3': '5', 'IS_SHOP': '1', 'value4': '0', 'value5': 'GA321D01H-K12'},
{'value1': '20150302', 'value2': '20150225', 'value3': '1', 'value4': '0', 'value5': '1', 'value6': 'GA321D01H-K12'}]
```

I'm trying to achieve it using a generator in order to avoid any memories issues, my current code is the following:

```
def csv_reader():
    with open('export.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield {key: value for key, value in row.items()}

generator = csv_reader() 
list = []
for i in generator:
    list.append(i)
```

The problem is that basically it runs out of memory because of the list becoming too big and the process is killed.
Is there a way to achieve the same result (list of dictonaries) in an efficient way? I'm very new to generators/yield so I don't even know if I'm using it correctly.

I also tried to use a virtual environment with pypy but the memory breaks anyway (a little later though).

Basically the reason why I want a list of dictionaries it that I want to try to convert the csv into an avro format using fastavro so any hints on how using fastavro (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastavro) without creating a list of dictionaries would be appreciated

Comment: If you store the complete results of the generator, you're not saving memory. If the goal is to process the file line by line, then process it line by line, don't store it. Also, side-note: `yield {key: value for key, value in row.items()}` is just shallow copying a `dict` when you already had a perfectly good `dict`, just do `yield row` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to convert from `csv` to `avro`, there is no reason to store a complete list of the input values. That's defeating the whole purpose of using the generator. It looks like, after setting up a schema, [`fastavro`'s `writer` is designed to take an iterable and write it out one record at a time](https://github.com/tebeka/fastavro/blob/master/fastavro/writer.py#L340), so you can just pass it the generator directly. For example, your code would simply omit the step of creating the `list` (side-note: Naming variables `list` is a bad idea, since it shadows/stomps the builtin name `list`), and just write the generator directly:

```
from fastavro import writer

def csv_reader():
    with open('export.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield row

    # If this is Python 3.3+, you could simplify further to just:
    with open('export.csv') as f:
        yield from csv.DictReader(f)

# schema could be from the keys of the first row which gets manually written
# or you can provide an explicit schema with documentation for each field
schema = {...}  

with open('export.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, schema, csv_reader())
```

The generator then produces one row at a time, and `writer` writes one row at a time. The input rows are discarded after writing, so memory usage remains minimal.

If you need to modify the rows, you'd modify the `row` in the `csv_reader` generator before `yield`-ing it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now I just need to understand how to use different codec in fastavro :D